# How do electric forces act on a magnetic dipole?

Tags: electromagnetism, dipole

Suppose a magnetic dipole (e.g a magnet, not a current loop) is immersed in an electric field.

What are the forces acting on it?

What about an electric dipole immersed in a magnetic field?

Comment: Why not a current loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forces in electrodynamics are governed by the Lorentz force law:
$$\vec{F}=q\left(\vec{E}+\vec{v}\times\vec{B}\right).$$
For a magnetic dipole in an electric field, the force is $0$, unless the magnetic dipole carries a charge, in which case the force is $q\vec{E}$, where $q$ is the total charge.

For an electric dipole in a magnetic field, the force is again zero if the dipole is initially stationary. If the dipole is not initially at rest, using the Lorentz force law and simplifying yields (assuming uniform $\vec{B}$)
$$\vec{F}=\left(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{p}\right)\times\vec{B},\ \ \ \ \ \vec{\tau}=\vec{p}\times\left(\vec{v}\times\vec{B}\right)$$
where $\vec{F}$ is the force on the dipole, $\vec{\tau}$ is the torque, $\vec{v}$ is the translation velocity, $\vec{\omega}$ is the angular velocity and $\vec{p}$ is the dipole moment.